# Access Violation when creating TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, access-violation

Using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, I have a unit (not a form or data module) with a custom class.  In this class I use an XML document - for the purpose of exporting DB data - as follows:

```
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    ...
    FDocument: IXMLDocument;
    ...
  protected
    ...
  public
    ...
  end;

  constructor TMyClass.Create(ADBConnection: TAdsConnection);
  begin
    ...
    FDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    ...
  end;
```

The general function of this class is to execute queries and write the result into `FDocument`, save to file, etc.

Whilst developing this class, everything was working fine.  Now I wanted to add some query statements (new tables in DB) and the code crashes (access violation) on the `FDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil)` statement. I can only use `nil` as parameter, as my class doesn't contain any `TComponent`.

An internet search gave me multiple clues on declaring `FDocument` as `IXMLDocument` (not as `TXMLDocument`) and reference counting (passing `nil` as Owner), but I think these are not applicable here for two reasons:

1. `FDocument` *IS* declared as `IXMLDocument`, and doesn't go out of scope until I release (destroy) `TMyClass` (i.e. there's no `Free` or alike).
2. The access violation occurs when executing the statement `FDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil)`, not thereafter.  Hence, I presume `FDocument` isn't even initialized and shouldn't influence the interface ref count.

The only thing that changed between the time I developed `TMyClass` and this problem occurring is that my PC was upgraded to Windows 10 Fall Creator (version 1703 -> 1709).

Can anyone give me a clue to what may cause this issue?  Could it be missing libraries (Window Update) or is that far fetched? Please note this is my first go at using XML, so I may be missing the obvious....

Comment: You should be calling [`NewXMLDocument()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.NewXMLDocument) instead of `TXMLDocument.Create(nil)` directly. But either way, know that by default, `TXMLDocument` uses MSXML on Windows, and MSXML is COM-based, so make sure that the thread that is creating the `TMyClass` object has initialized COM with `CoInitialize/Ex()` before creating the `TXMLDocument` object (the VCL does that automatically in the main UI thread for you, but you have to do it manually in worker threads, and in the main thread in a non-VCL app).

Comment: Make sure you are not accidentally calling create on the *variable* name instead of the Class Type. Something like var MyClass: TMyClass; MyClass := MyClass.Create; Notice the missing "T" on the call to .Create right after the equal sign. This will compile and run but will exception as you describe.

Comment: @RemyLebeau; Just out of interest, why is NewXmlDocument() preferred over Create(nil)?

Comment: @user8425066 Because `NewXMLDocument()` returns an `IXMLDocument`, hiding the *implementation detail* that a `TXMLDocument` object was created with a `nil` owner to enable reference counting semantics. It is just a cleaner and safer way to construct a blank `IXMLDocument` (there are also sibling [`LoadXMLDocument()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.LoadXMLDocument) and [`LoadXMLData()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.LoadXMLData) functions for getting an `IXMLDocument` from an XML file and XML string, respectively).

Comment: FYI, when you find your own solution to a question, you should post it as an answer, not edit the question. You can post your own answers to your own questions. "*I am populating the array before creating the `IXMLDocument`, so I would expect an "index out of bounds" error for the array (e.g. using `FMyArray[**5**]` on `FMyArray: array [0 .. **4**] of TMyObject;`)*" - [Range Checks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Range_checking) are disabled by default.

Comment: @RemyLebeau; Will do the next time (will also highlight as 'code' rather than italics).  I forgot that arrays behave different than TStringlist w.r.t. range checking.  Enabling range checking, the exception is raised at the procedure call to populate the array.  With range checking disabled, the code just continues and then fails at the create statement for the XML document.  This misguided me into suspecting the XML to be the culprit....

Comment: Actually, you should do it this time. You can move the solution to the answer space below, and then either delete the newly added content of the question or use the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49637630/revisions) to roll back to the version prior to your solution being added.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Created a unit with a new class (`TTestClass`) having just a single field `FDocument` (i.e. similar to `TMyClass` but all the other stuff stripped out).  From a test app, creating `TTestClass` was no problem; even with `Create(nil)`.

I then tried to create a `TMyClass` from the test app.  As before, this crashed with an AV. To be precise; in `System._IntfCopy` at `CALL DWORD PTR [EAX] + VMTOFFSET IInterface._Release`. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of assembly, so I decided to look in the 'different code' between `TTestClass` and `TMyClass`.

The source of this problem turns out to be a silly mistake. The query statements (for exporting the data as described) are held in a static array of objects.  I added the query object, but forgot to increase the dimension of the array (i.e. the array is declared smaller than the number of objects I'm trying to store).

The thing I don't understand though, is how this causes `TXMLDocument.Create(nil)` to fail. I am populating the array before creating the `IXMLDocument`, so I would expect an "index out of bounds" error for the array (e.g. using `FMyArray[**5**]` on `FMyArray: array [0 .. **4**] of TMyObject;`).  However, this didn't happen and an AV was raised trying to create the `IXMLDocument`.

Comment: It is not the `TXMLDocument.Create(nil)` call failing. The call is never made in your case. If your class` fields are defined like this `private  FMyArray: array[0..4] of TMyObject; FDocument: IXMLDocument; ...` and you write with `FMyArray[5] := <somevalue>` you also modify the field `FDocument` which then points to a wrong memory location. Then, in your assignment `FDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil)` the compiler checks if `FDocument <> nil` and therefore tries to release the interface.